# code to display the text TRUE

Tags: linux, shell, centos, scripting

I'm trying to display the text TRUE to the screen if a file is tested to have the readable bit set using the if then statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [[ -r /path/to/your/file ]]; then
  echo "TRUE"
fi
```

Comment: Since `-r` is supported by `[`, you might as well use it to make it portable. (And the question doesn't state that they're using bash.)

Comment: @user1700494 do you think [[ would work ?